Is it illegal in Australia to add "chocolate or sultanas" to an Anzac biscuit?
QI - Quite Interesting is a Facebook page ostensibly connected to the popular British TV show. The page has approximately 524 thousand followers.
They posted an image on 26 July 2024. After three days, it has around 1700 reactions and 480 comments and 180 shares, claiming

In Australia, commercial bakers can be jailed for up to a year for adding chocolate chips or sultanas to Anzac biscuits.


A search pops up numerous articles supposedly backing the claim, including the extremely assertive Pedestrian.tv article titled "You Could Cop A Legit $50k Fine For Trying To Fuck With Anzac Biscuits
":

With Anzac Day 2019 on Thursday, the Department of Veteran’s Affairs has issued a reminder to all Australians that it is actually very illegal – an offence under the Crimes Act 1914, no less – to alter, vary, re-interpret, or mislabel the traditional Anzac Biscuit, with enforceable fines totalling tens of thousands of dollars on the line for anyone who goes off-book.

But a search of Australia's federal Crimes Act 1914 turns up no mention of "anzac" or "biscuit", let alone the phrase of both together.
Is this really a legitimate obscure regulation that I cannot find directly, yet another "weird old law that still exists" meme with no grounding in fact, or something in between?

Dear visitors from Hot Network Questions. Welcome to Skeptics! Please read that link before posting an answer, or especially posting a pseudo-answer in a comment.

Use of the word "Anzac" is regulated by Australia’s Department of Veterans' Affairs, and they would never give a permit for a "Anzac" recipe that deviates too much from their ideal (as the examples given in the question do). The penalty for violating this law is imprisonment or a fine. However, the same recipe sold under a name that doesn't include the word "Anzac" would not be a violation.
The Smithsonian gives a good summary:

While some grandmothers add in extra butter, nuts and even eggs for a crispier and richer mouthfeel, commercial bakeries are unable to steer away from the good ol' Aussie Anzac biscuit recipe unless given permission by the governing body: Australia's Department of Veterans' Affairs (DVA). Many businesses that have tried to push boundaries by riffing off the traditional Anzac biscuit recipe have been caught and punished for such offenses as adding chocolate chips or sultanas---a jail-worthy crime, according to the DVA.

The last link, from the Australian Department of Veteran Affairs, is very explicit (emphasis added):

Where a recipe or the finished product substantially deviate from the generally accepted form (e.g. include ingredients such as chocolate or fruit), the manufacturer should consider renaming them so that the word ‘Anzac’ is not used.
[...]
Each year DVA declines applications for permits where products include
the word ‘Anzac’ but which do not conform or bear any resemblance to generally accepted forms of Anzac biscuits – some examples include ‘Choc Chip Anzac Biscuits’, ‘Anzac cheesecake’, ‘Anzac muffin’ and ‘Anzac sandwich’.

It also outlines the penalties for any entity that violates these regulations:


Under the Protection of Word ‘Anzac’ Act 1920, a penalty of up to 12 months imprisonment can be applied for breaches of the Regulations.
Under the Crimes Act 1914, financial penalties for an individual or a company may be imposed by the Court, instead of imprisonment.



Interesting. You found the 2020 guidelines. The 2018 ones did not appear to have the explicit prohibition against chocolate! (Although it did not appear on the external list of 'traditional' ingredients linked in the 2018 version.) So, they are apparently tightening the def, or at least making the prohibition more explicit.

Also the SMH piece claims that they were sent to troops during WWI, but another piece I found quoting some historians says that is a myth.

@Believeitornot It's not necessarily tightening the definition; the use of a parenthetical "e.g." implies they consider it merely highlighting something that would already have been implied by the general definition, rather than adding restrictions that wouldn't have applied were they not mentioned explicitly. Which would make sense if, as they say, they keep receiving and declining applications for recipes that add chocolate to use the Anzac name; they were already prohibiting chocolate, now they're just trying to stop people from wasting time applying.

@Ben: I've looked at the application form. They don't solicit the recipe from the applicant. It's taken as an implicit commitment to follow the guidelines. The form only instructs the applicant to 'view' the guidelines.

@Believeitornot... Sure. Whether they're declining based on actually reviewing the recipe or just seeing the product name is "Choc Chip Anzac Biscuits" isn't strongly connected to what I was saying. Which was just that it looks to me like they are saying they already would have declined the same "Choc Chip Anzac Cookie" under the 2018 guidelines, and the explicit mention of chocolate in the updated guidelines isn't intended to tighten the definition or change any application outcomes, but to head off more applications with no chance before they are made.

Although the recipe has evolved over time, 2018 Australian government regulations appear to prohibit departing from the "traditional" recipe. (And that's a way of me saying I don't know when these regulations were first introduced.) But breaching these [updatable] regulations while using the Anzac name is indeed punishable by (fairly old) law[s].

Penalties for breaching the Regulations Under the Protection of Word ‘Anzac’ Act 1920, a penalty of up to 12 months imprisonment can be applied for breaches of the Regulations.
Under the Crimes Act 1914, a penalty of up to $10,200 for a natural person and $51,000 for a body corporate may be imposed by the Court, instead of imprisonment.
[...]
Anzac Biscuits
The production of Anzac Biscuits is the only purely commercial use of the word ‘Anzac’ that is generally approved.
However, such products must:

not substantially deviate from the traditional recipe and shape
be referred to as 'Anzac Biscuits' or 'Anzac Slice', not 'Anzac Cookies'
not use the word 'Anzac' inappropriately—such as disrespectful advertising.


Those are Australian government guidelines, for the interpretation of said Regulations. They link to https://www.awm.gov.au/node/20119 for the approved/traditional recipe. Which is a dead link now, but in 2018 had this:

Ingredients sufficient for six biscuits:

200 gm/1.5cups/300 mls flour
400 gm/3 cups/600 mls wholemeal flour
40 gm/5 tbls sugar
20 gm/3 tbls milk powder
1.5 gm/good pinch salt
220 mls water

Use self-raising flours. If self-raising flours are not available, sieve 10 grams of baking powder together with plain flour before adding other ingredients. [...]
The rolled sheet of dough is then cut into 90 mm squares [...]
Next, the biscuit squares should be docked by having a regular horizontal and vertical pattern of holes pushed into them at about 18 mm spaces with a flat-ended pin or rod. Push it in until it bottoms, twist slightly, and then withdraw. Repeat at the next position. Each biscuit should have five vertical and five horizontal rows of docker holes, 25 holes in all. There are those at the Memorial who argue for 49 holes (7 x 7) as the authentic number of docker holes.

Exactly how much of a departure from that would be [or was ever] deemed punishable in an Australian court of law is hard for me to say.
N.B. Nate Eldridge correctly points out that that (Australian War Memorial) page in fact contains several recipes. The above is for "Army" or "tile" Anzac "very, very had" biscuits. They give another for softer ones containing oats, and optionally coconut.
Also, the prohibition appears to me to be valid only for commercially sold products. The Regulation itself is attached at the end of those guidelines. The longest part of it (2) deals with defining whom it applies to. Essentially the government can refuse to license the use of the word 'Anzac' to biscuits or anything it doesn't like. And commercially using 'Anzac' without a license is violation of law. Biscuits themselves are never actually mentioned in the Regulation itself (but only in the Guidelines).
The definition of commercial is quite broad though. E.g. if you're a doctor's office that gives out free 'Anzac' cookies, it probably still applies to said cookies:

2[.] Prohibition of use in trade etc of word ‘Anzac’
(1) No person shall, without the authority of the Minister, proof
whereof shall lie upon the person accused, assume or use the
word ‘Anzac’ or any word resembling the word ‘Anzac’ in
connexion with any trade, business, calling or profession or in
connexion with any entertainment or any lottery or art union or
as the name or part of the name of any private residence, boat,
vehicle or charitable or other institution, or any building in
connexion therewith. [...]
(2) Without limiting the meaning of subregulation (1) a word shall
be deemed to be assumed or used by a person in connexion with
any trade, business, calling or profession if:
(a) it is applied (whether as a trade mark or otherwise) to any
goods manufactured, produced, sold or offered for sale by
that person;

(Also, as Oddthinking rightfully pointed out in a comment, the name "Crimes Act 1914" is also somewhat misleading [in this context], as the Act has been amended numerous times over the years.)

N.B. Under the original 1921 Regulations the penalty was "One hundred pounds or imprisonment for six months, or both". It was surely increased to the levels quoted in my answer sometime thereafter.

So, the penalty is basically for false advertising (calling something an Anzac Biscuit that doesn't meet the strict definition of what it is)?

Wait, the page you linked has two very different recipes. The first one, headed "Anzac tile / wafer recipe" is something hard and dry. The latter, with butter and oats and much more sugar, is the one that corresponds to what's usually called "Anzac biscuits", I think.

@NateEldredge: you're right about that. I didn't read the full page. Oddly the Guidelines only mentioned one kind of biscuits [and no 'tiles']. OTOH, the biscuits recipe on the Memorial page includes "rolled oats" for instance, while the tiles do not have that. Besides the shape difference, of course. They even entertain two recipes for [oat-containing] 'biscuits' as such--coconut is optional.
